# Why not global $db in model classes?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

Let's say that we have a MVC pattern. If we have something like this:

**blog_controller.php**

```
<?php

class c_blog{
    private $model;

    public function __construct(){
         include( [model_path] );
         $this->model = new m_blog();
    }

    public function post_list(){
         return $this->model->get_list();
    }
}
```

**blog_model.php**

```
<?php

class m_blog{
     public function get_list(){
         global $db;
         $sel = $db->query("...");
         $sel = $db->fetch_array($sel);
         return $sel;
     }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

$db = new database();
include "blog_controller.php";
$blog = new c_blog();
var_dump( $blog->post_list() );

?>
```

Why the above example isn't good, and a lot of devs want `OOP` like `class m_blog extends database{}` ?

---

I want only the advantages and disavantages, because I use this "worry" method on over 15 sites with a high traffic and I don't have problems (some of that websites work with multidatabases and it's very easy to change global `$db`, to global `$db_five`.)

Thanks!

Comment: Because using `global` in cases like this is bad practice. There are more efficient alternatives like injecting the `$db` object into the class. Commonly referred to as [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: you want to say that is ok something like that: creating a __construct in model, and a $dataconnection variable in model, and in a function instead calling global $db; $db->query(), doing: $this->dataconnection->query() ?

Comment: Something exactly like that yes! Essentially sharing the resource among the classes. (*That isn't the exactly terminology I'd use, but thats it*)

Comment: Just cover your simple code with phpunit - and you will understand why better use oop, dependency injection, mvc, patterns etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use inheritance?

```
<?php

class model {
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->initDb();
    }

    private function initDb();
}

class c_blog {
    private $model;

    public function __construct(){
         include( [model_path] );
         $this->model = new m_blog();
    }

    public function post_list(){
         return $this->model->get_list();
    }
}

class m_blog extends model{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct;
    }
     public function get_list(){
         $sel = $this->db->query("...");
         $sel = $this->db->fetch_array($sel);
         return $sel;
     }
}
```

Comment: it's ok but not fit my problems. I want to be able to use $db everywhere in my code. I don't want to change everything to be in OOP because I have a lot of newbies. And if I initiate that $model->db .. I will have 2 instances of same db connection.. :(

Comment: Then I would recommend using a static variable for $db in the model class.

Comment: @MihaiZinculescu If your software was broken into distinct layers you would not need to have access to your database everywhere. Each layer has it owns responsibilities with the database related functionality in a data access layer (DAL).

Comment: I have more $db_x instances. the idea is that I want to call $db instance even in viewer part (easy for newbies). (like wordpress)

Comment: That is not proper MVC. You should connect to the DB in models, display content in views, and use the controllers as the 'glue'.